# Migrating Python Selenium web scrapers to remote server

Tags: python, selenium

I have a number of web scrapers built with Selenium in Python that run 24/7 for several months of the year. At the moment, all scrapers run locally on my PC. This comes at quite a cost to the performance of my PC and basically means it's constantly working fairly hard.

Ideally I would like to use remote servers instead but not really sure where to start. I would like to be able to run these things remotely, speed is also quite important - the pages need to load fairly quickly. What would be worth looking into? I'm willing to pay for a quality service.

Thanks

Comment: Python has also scraping module [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) and authors have also server for running it - [zyte](https://www.zyte.com/) (formely `Scrapinghub`). Maybe it would be good start

Comment: [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/selenium-webdriver-tutorial) has functions to run `Selenium`

Comment: you could run it even on other servers but you would have to check if portal allow for scraping - some portals may block access to external servers to stop using portal to sending spam or hack other servers.

Comment: on page [Selenium.dev](https://www.selenium.dev/)  you can see `"Selenium Level Sponsors"` with links to portals which offer some function with `Selenium`

Comment: I found also [Awesome Selenium](https://github.com/christian-bromann/awesome-selenium) and it has list of some [cloud services](https://github.com/christian-bromann/awesome-selenium#cloud-services)